# pop up div tag only once after successfull login

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

In my site am doing popup div with colorbox (in master page).my req is i want to popup this color box only once and that to after login only.
`Hi , In my site am doing popup div with colorbox (in master page). its working fine. but i want to pop up this colorbox div after successfull login. this is also done. but my req is i want to popup this color box only once and that to after login only. so could u give any suggestion to find the page is loading firsttime or second time. not using (!ispostback concept in page load)`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var hfClose = $('#hfCloseColorbox').val();
            var page = $(location).attr('pathname');  // index.php 
            if (page == '/Default.aspx') {
                if (hfClose == '2') {
                    $.colorbox({ width: "32%", inline: true, href: "#DisplayChat" });
                }
            }
        }); 
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (hfCloseColorbox.Value == "")
                hfCloseColorbox.Value = "2";
            else if (ViewState["count"] == null)
                hfCloseColorbox.Value = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(hfCloseColorbox.Value) + 1);
            else if (ViewState["count"].ToString() == "1")
                hfCloseColorbox.Value = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(ViewState["count"].ToString()) + 1);

            hfCloseColorbox.Value = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(hfCloseColorbox.Value) + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            if (ViewState["count"] == null)
                hfCloseColorbox.Value = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(hfCloseColorbox.Value) + 1);
            else if (ViewState["count"].ToString() == "1")
                hfCloseColorbox.Value = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(ViewState["count"].ToString()) + 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create own special variable within ViewState to determine if page is loaded for the first time (after login).

```
if (ViewState["Foo"] != null && ViewState["Foo"] == "True")
{
    // Code for Pop-Up display
}
```

Only place that will assign value for ViewState["Foo"] is code after successful login.